# Handsontable - Input validation, limit to numbers including decimal points

Tags: asp.net, validation, numeric, handsontable

I am using Handsontable jQuery plugin to build an excel like grid. Finally I will have to save this table data into an excel file. I am using ASP.NET.

My question:
I want to limit all the cells of the table to take only Numbers including decimal points. I am planning to use OnBeforeChange callback. I am stuck at exactly enforcing this validation, as the cells are not input boxes(so, I cannot use jQuery.numeric plugin or similar). Do I have to use Math functions and code from scratch or is there any other easier way of accomplishing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You must add numeric properties to columns:

```
jQuery( '#dataTable').handsontable({
    data: data,
    ...,
    columns: [
        {
            // To allow only numbers 
            type: 'numeric', 
            // Mask, if you enter 0 it will display 0.00,
            // if you enter 4 it will display 4.00
            // if you enter .5 it will display 0.50
            // if you enter 4.5 it will display 4.50
            // if you enter NaN it will display 0.00
            format: '0.00' 
        }
    ]
});
```

Handsontable uses Numeral.js for formating numbers, you can check ot here: http://numeraljs.com/